# Trouble getting the values of an array of buttons in a JPanel from action listener

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener

I'm trying to add logic to a GUI game of TicTacToe. The game class sets up a panel of buttons and works as intended (I put the code for it here in case it's needed). I am looking to add a checker method in the `Button` class. However I have a huge roadblock that I can't think of a solution to get around.

I want the checker method to somehow get the value of a particular button assigned in the `actionPerformed` method in the `Button` class. For example, if 3 consecutive buttons in a row have the same value then based on the value either X or O's win. I'm not sure if the way I have this set up even allows this but I think there is a way I may just not be thinking about.

---

### The Game Class

Creates an array of buttons, buttons are made using the `Button` class.

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class game extends JFrame {
    JPanel buttonBoard = new JPanel();
    Button buttons[] = new Button [9];
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new game();
    }
    
    public game() {
        super("TicTacToe");
        setSize(600, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        
        buttonBoard.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new Button();
            buttonBoard.add(buttons[i]);
        }
        
        add(buttonBoard);
        setResizable(false);
    }

}
```

### The Button Class

Creates an `X` and `O` ImageIcon. Has an ActionListener that sets the buttons accordingly.

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Button extends JButton implements ActionListener {
    ImageIcon x, o;
    byte value = 0;
    
    public Button() {
        x = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("x.png"));
        o = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("o.png"));
        
        this.addActionListener(this);
    }
    
    public void checker(Button array[]) {
        array[i].
    }
        
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        value++;
        
        if (value > 2)
            value = 0;
            
            switch(value) {
            case 0:
                setIcon(null);
                break;

            case 1:
                setIcon(x);
                break;

            case 2:
                setIcon(o);
                break;

            }
            
    }

}
```

If any more information is needed please drop a comment. This is my first time programming a GUI and I'm trying to learn my way around, so if you have any tips I would appreciate those also.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Button should not maintain the state of the game, should merely display it. The state of the game should be somewhere else, possibly matrix in Game class. Aka separate domain from presentation: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SeparateDomainFromPresentation

Comment: If this were my project, I 1) wouldn't extend JButton, 2) would not have a GUI class implement a listener. 3) Rather would create a non-GUI model class to hold the logic of the program.

Comment: The above comments address the main issue(s) and I agree with them. I just thought I should mention, in case you are unaware, that an `if(...)` statement with no brackets (`{...}`) only executes the code up to the next semi-colon. Your code indentation in the `actionPerformed` method is contrary to what actually occurs.

Comment: @JonnyHenly: looks like he planned it that way.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ahh looking back I see that the `if` statement is there to reset `value` and that the `switch` should run regardless of the `if` outcome. While the indentation suggests otherwise, it can probably be blamed on the auto code formatting of an IDE or user error.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments above, it would be best to keep the logic out of the view components. To help with the original question about getting at your array values here's a quick example that might help based on the code you provided

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JFrame {

    JPanel buttonBoard = new JPanel();
    Button buttons[] = new Button [9];
    boolean playerOne = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game();
    }

    public Game() {
        super("TicTacToe");
        setSize(600, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        buttonBoard.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

        final ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() instanceof  Button) {
                    if (isPlayerOne()) {
                        ((Button) e.getSource()).setValue(1);
                    } else {
                        ((Button) e.getSource()).setValue(2);
                    }
                    nextPlayer();
                }
            }
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new Button(0);
            buttons[i].addActionListener(listener);
            buttonBoard.add(buttons[i]);
        }

        add(buttonBoard);
        setResizable(false);
    }

    private boolean isPlayerOne() {
        return playerOne;
    }

    private void nextPlayer() {
        playerOne = !playerOne;
    }

    public class Button extends JButton {

        ImageIcon x, o;
        int value = 0;

        public Button(int initialValue) {
            x = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("x.png"));
            o = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("o.png"));
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(final int valueIn) {
            value = valueIn;
            updatedIcon();
        }

        private void updatedIcon() {
            switch(value) {
            case 0:
                setIcon(null);
                break;

            case 1:
                setIcon(x);
                break;

            case 2:
                setIcon(o);
                break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting thank you. I am still confused when making decisions on how things should be set up but thanks!